# Unhandled Rejection: default.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, get, axios

I'm trying to make a simple get request using axios in my react component using the following function:

```
import React from 'react';
import api from '../../assets/API';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function Chart() {
    const [apiData, setDataApi] = useState({ elements: [] });

    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await api.get('/countries');
        setDataApi(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
    }, []);

    console.log(apiData);

    return(
        <h1>.</h1>
    )
}
```

The api.js looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';


const api = axios.get({
    baseURL: 'https://api.covid19api.com',
})

export default api;
```

I'm facing the following errors:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _assets_API__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.get is not a function
    at fetchData (Chart.js:10)
    at Chart.js:13
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:19731)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:19769)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:22853)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:22820)
    at react-dom.development.js:22699
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:597)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:552)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:164)
```

I've tried to clear cache and used *yarn install* to make sure I had everything in the project, but didn't worked. I'm also receiving an empty array in the **console.log(apiData)**, but I'm afraid it's related to the error, since I tried with other APIs and faced the same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple mistake =)

api.js:

```
const api = axios.get({
    baseURL: 'https://api.covid19api.com',
})
```

In the above code, where you define your API, you should use `axios.create` instead of `axios.get`.

At the moment, if you look carefully, in your React component you're basically calling `axios.get().get()` which doesn't make sense.